# Tag synonymous appears twice in the auto-completition

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I verified this problem on english.stackexchange.com; I was writing a tag, and the auto-completion shown the complete tag twice: in one case it was followed by the number of questions using it, and in the other case was followed by *(s)*.

[image: word-definition auto-complete]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked in a fix that will be deployed tomorrow.

This happens when you have a pending merge on a tag synonym, for example in english there is a synonym in place from `word-definition` -> `meaning`, however admins have not merged the old occurrence of `word-definition`